# MySQL /Java help - Update Method via eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm working on a task for my bootcamp, and this one point is stumping me, details of task are below.

Task:

> Create a java program that works with mySQL. The program should
> present the user with the following menu:
>
> 1. Enter toy
> 2. Update toy
> 3. Delete toy
> 4. Search toy
> 5. Exit

I've created the whole program and tested it with the database I set up and all aspects and their methods work - except the update toy method. I've put put in a pic of the database for reference and the Update method as I have it, this is about the 5th reworking, I know it's wrong but nothing I've tried has worked. Any advice or explanation as to where I'm going wrong would be helpful - if you can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

[Database ref pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2X7w.png)

```java
static void updateMethod() {
    // the connection
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/toyshop";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "SlytherinPr1de";
        
        try {
            Connection conUpdate = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
            System.out.println("Connected to Database - start with record update:");
            
            //set up method
            //get the id of the item to update so it can be found in the table and updated:
            Scanner updateRow = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the id of the item you wish to update: ");
            String toyToUpdate = updateRow.nextLine();
            
            Scanner update1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the new toy name: ");
            String nameUpdate1 = update1.nextLine();
            
            Scanner update2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the new company: ");
            String compUpdate2 = update2.nextLine();
            
            Scanner update3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the new quantity: ");
            String qtyUpdate3 = update3.nextLine();
            
            String sql = "UPDATE toys SET name=" + nameUpdate1 + ",company=" + compUpdate2 + ",Qty=" + qtyUpdate3 + ",WHERE id =" + toyToUpdate;
            
            
            PreparedStatement statement = conUpdate.prepareStatement(sql);
            
                
            int rowsUpdated = sql;
                            
                if(rowsUpdated > 0) {
                    System.out.println("The existing record for toy ID " + toyToUpdate + " has been successfully updated.");
                    }
                
                updateRow.close();
                update1.close();
                update2.close();
                update3.close();
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Method Error - check code and retry.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Where are the commas?

Comment: I have updated to contain commas as suggested :)

Comment: comma WHERE isn't a thing.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should **never** concatenate values into a query string. Instead use parameter placeholders and a prepared statement, then **set** the values of the parameters on the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st problem with your code is the use of 4 `Scanner` objects to retrieve the input data.
You need only 1 `Scanner`.

The 2nd problem is the syntax of the SQL statement.
Commas are needed to separate the columns that you want to update.
Also the string parameter values must be enclosed inside single quotes, but this is not the safe and recommended way.
Since you are using a `PreparedStatement` you should also `?` placeholders for each of the string parameters and pass their values with the method `setString()`:

```
static void updateMethod() {
    // the connection
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/toyshop";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "SlytherinPr1de";

    try {
        Connection conUpdate = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        System.out.println("Connected to Database - start with record update:");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the id of the item you wish to update: ");
        String toyToUpdate = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the new toy name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the new company: ");
        String company = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the new quantity: ");
        String qty = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();

        String sql = "UPDATE toys SET name = ?, company = ?, Qty = ? WHERE id = ?";
        PreparedStatement statement = conUpdate.prepareStatement(sql);
        
        statement.setString(1, name);
        statement.setString(2, company);
        statement.setString(3, qty);
        statement.setString(4, toyToUpdate);

        int rowsUpdated = statement.executeUpdate();

        if(rowsUpdated > 0) {
            System.out.println("The existing record for toy ID " + toyToUpdate + " has been successfully updated.");
        }

        statement.close();
        conUpdate.close();
    }catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Method Error - check code and retry.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much - I didnt realize that about the scanners as its never been corrected by the teachers -_- Thank you again, I will be correcting the rest of the methods to follow that with the scanner as well.

Comment: @Nyxerian and don't forget to accept the answer if this answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be that you are using wrong datatypes as you are inserting all "String values" in the table for every column, but since other functions work I'd assume that all the columns in the table have datatype of String

I can see one error in the update statement, i.e you forgot to add a **coma after each field in update statement**

*Semi colon* is missing as well, but since its a single statement, it should work without semi colon as well, though *generally it adds semi colon automatically in single statements but I would still suggest to add it manually*)

The statement should be:

```
String sql = "UPDATE toys SET name = " + nameUpdate1 + ", company = " + compUpdate2 + ", Qty = " + qtyUpdate3 + "WHERE id = " + toyToUpdate + ";";
```

The syntax for the update statement is:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN 
WHERE [condition];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply - i'll take a look. and yes, they are all set to string for simplicity sake.